# Google chart x axis with decimal places

Tags: html, google-api

I'm attempting to create a basic google chart. 
X axis is a time, y axis is a value. 
Data is formatted as so:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'Time');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Yesterday');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Today');
      data.addColumn('number', 'TwoDayAgo');

      data.addRows([
        [01.00,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
        [02.00,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
        [03.00,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
        [04.00,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
        [05.00,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4]
      ]);

      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Results',
          subtitle: 'Comparison'
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="linechart_material"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the decimal places in the data table. 
If I remove the decimal places it will work om
However the chart does not show?

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204678/how-to-format-numbers-in-google-api-linechart