# Display thousound with point in Google chart API

Tags: charts, google-visualization

is there a way to display a thousand number in the format 1.200,55 instead of 1,200.55?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204678/how-to-format-numbers-in-google-api-linechart contains a good answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a section in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat) about `numberformats`. What you'd need to set are `decimalSymbol` and `groupingSymbol`.

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
{decimalSymbol: ',', groupingSymbol: '.'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another way in order to customize text for a country or language, affecting the formatting of values such as currencies, dates, and numbers.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#loadwithlocale