# Format numbers on google bar chart with dual x-Axes (decimal)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, decimal

How is it possible to format the number values on a google bar chart with dual x-Axes? 
The top axes with the label support should have at least four decimal places, like the value shown in the tooltip.

What I have tried is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204678/how-to-format-numbers-in-google-api-linechart) approach, but it doesn't seem to work.

My code:

```
data.addColumn('string', 'RuleName');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Lift');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Support');


        for (var i = 0; i < chartsdata.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([rule, Lift,Support)]);
        }

        // format numbers in second column to 5 decimals
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
            pattern: '#,##0.00000'
        }); // This does work, but only for the value in the tooltip.

        formatter.format(data, 2);

        // Passing in some options    
        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barChart'));
        var options = {

            title: "Association Rules by lift and support",
            bars: 'horizontal',
            series: {
                0: { axis: 'Lift', targetAxisIndex: 0, },
                1: { axis: 'Support', targetAxisIndex: 1}

            },

            axes: {
                x: {
                    Lift: { label: 'Lift', format: '0,000' //Doesn't work,  }, // Bottom x-axis.
                    Support: { side: 'top', label: 'Support' } // Top x-axis.
                }
            }, ..........
```

What I also tried is this approach from the google doc:

```
series:{hAxes:{1:{title:'abc', format: '0,0000'}}
```

[image: The top axes with the label support should have at least four decimal places]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several options that are not supported by *Material* charts
see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

although `format` is not listed, there are several options not supported for --> `{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}`

so that could be the problem
note: the above options should stand alone and not be included in the `series` option,
as seen in the question (*What I also tried...*)

you can change both x-axis formats by using `hAxis.format`
but don't think you'll be able to change just one

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['bar']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'RuleName');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Lift');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Support');
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    data.addRow([i.toString(), i+2, i+3]);
  }

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#,##0.00000'
  });
  formatter.format(data, 2);

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barChart'));
  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Association Rules by lift and support'
    },
    bars: 'horizontal',
    series: {
      0: {axis: 'Lift'},
      1: {axis: 'Support'}
    },
    axes: {
      x: {
        Lift: {label: 'Lift'},
        Support: {side: 'top', label: 'Support'}
      }
    },
    hAxis: {
      format: '#,##0.00000'
    },
    height: 320
  };
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="barChart"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, with _Material_, be sure to use `convertOptions` before drawing...

Comment: This helps definitely! I did try the `hAxis: {
      format: '#,##0.00000'
    }` option, but didn't know about `convertOptions`. This solved my problem, by formatting both axes.